# When should I remove popcorn from the microwave?

Tags: food, appliances, time, snack-food

I'd like to know exactly when to remove popcorn from the microwave. If I leave it in a little longer, a few more kernels will pop, but I might burn the popcorn. if I take it out too early I may leave some unpopped kernels. Usually one listens for when popping stops, or when the last pop happened, but some bags of popcorn finish much faster, so that means there's more time until burnt.

Comment: I actually do pretty good with this. I thought it would be fun to ask.

Comment: As you already mentioned about waiting for kernels to pop, I don't think it will be and answer: Wait until most of the kernels pop, then take your popcorn out. It usually happens in 3 to 5 minutes (http://www.realsimple.com/food-recipes/cooking-tips-techniques/cooking-uses-for-your-microwave/make-popcorn) if cooking them on high power.

Comment: If we get a new brand of popcorn I want to tell my wife to wait X number of minutes and seconds without having to do trial and error myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take it out once the pops are more than one second apart. Although this will leave some unpopped kernels, it will prevent the popped kernels from burning.

Comment: I found in my microwave the popcorn doesn't start burning until it gets close to five minutes total time. Going much over that, even if still popping good, it will likely burn or take on a burned taste.